# Proxmox PCIe Passthrough is not working

Tags: qemu, proxmox

I am trying to pass through a network device to a VM running pfSense and I cannot get it working. When I start pfSense the network card is not visible at all. I think I have set everything up properly, can anyone suggest what is wrong?

Installed PCI devices are:

```
# lspci -nn
<snip>
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V [8086:15bc] (rev 10)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10d3]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
```

The device I want to pass through is 01:00.0

Listing the hardware returns:

```
# Ishw -class network
<snip>
*-network
description: Ethernet controller
product: 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
version: 00
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list rom
configuration: driver=vfio-pci latency=0
resources: irq:16 memory:a13c0000-a13dffff memory:a1300000-a137ffff ioport:4000(size=32) memory:a13e0000-a13e3fff memory:a1380000-a13bffff
```

The VMID is 100, and /etc/pve/qemu-server/100.conf contains:

```
bootdisk: virtio0
cores: 2
hostpci1: 01:00,pcie=1,rombar=0
ide2: NAS1:iso/pfSense-CE-2.4.4-RELEASE-p3-amd64.iso,media=cdrom
machine: q35
memory: 2048
name: pfSense
net0: virtio=16:B9:C8:87:DE:54,bridge=vmbr1,firewall=1
numa: 0
onboot: 1
ostype: l26
scsihw: virtio-scsi-pci
smbios1: uuid=a18cecad-2bf6-4e81-ad32-aa2b2d7d0142
sockets: 1
usb0: host=148f:2573,usb3=1
virtio0: local-lvm:vm-100-disk-0,size=32G
vmgenid: 412dae1f-41c4-49eb-9a58-398bd33c350b
```

/etc/default/grub has the following:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet intel_iommu=on"
```

/etc/modules contains:

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
vfio
vfio_iommu_type1
vfio_pci
vfio_virqfd
```

Validating it is all enabled (this is a bit different to the doco)

```
# dmesg | grep -e DMAR -e IOMMU -e AMD-Vi
[ 0.012056] ACPI: DMAR 0x000000007E41DBC0 0000A8 (v01 INTEL EDK2 00000002 01000013)
[ 0.182375] DMAR: IOMMU enabled
[ 0.349186] DMAR: Host address width 39
[ 0.349187] DMAR: DRHD base: 0x000000fed90000 flags: 0x0
[ 0.349192] DMAR: dmar0: reg_base_addr fed90000 ver 1:0 cap 1c0000c40660462 ecap 19e2ff0505e
[ 0.349193] DMAR: DRHD base: 0x000000fed91000 flags: 0x1
[ 0.349196] DMAR: dmar1: reg_base_addr fed91000 ver 1:0 cap d2008c40660462 ecap f050da
[ 0.349197] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x0000007e704000 end: 0x0000007e94dfff
[ 0.349198] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x0000007f800000 end: 0x0000008fffffff
[ 0.349200] DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 2 under DRHD base 0xfed91000 IOMMU 1
[ 0.349201] DMAR-IR: HPET id 0 under DRHD base 0xfed91000
[ 0.349201] DMAR-IR: Queued invalidation will be enabled to support x2apic and Intr-remapping.
[ 0.351514] DMAR-IR: Enabled IRQ remapping in x2apic mode
[ 1.315529] DMAR: No ATSR found
[ 1.315585] DMAR: dmar0: Using Queued invalidation
[ 1.315588] DMAR: dmar1: Using Queued invalidation
[ 1.345917] DMAR: Intel(R) Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O
```

Checking they are all in different groups returns:

```
# find /sys/kernel/iommu_groups/ -type l
/sys/kernel/iommu_groups/7/devices/0000:00:1c.0
/sys/kernel/iommu_groups/5/devices/0000:00:16.0
/sys/kernel/iommu_groups/3/devices/0000:00:12.0
/sys/kernel/iommu_groups/11/devices/0000:03:00.0
/sys/kernel/iommu_groups/1/devices/0000:00:01.0
/sys/kernel/iommu_groups/1/devices/0000:01:00.0
/sys/kernel/iommu_groups/8/devices/0000:00:1c.6
/sys/kernel/iommu_groups/6/devices/0000:00:17.0
/sys/kernel/iommu_groups/4/devices/0000:00:14.2
/sys/kernel/iommu_groups/4/devices/0000:00:14.0
/sys/kernel/iommu_groups/2/devices/0000:00:02.0
/sys/kernel/iommu_groups/10/devices/0000:02:00.0
/sys/kernel/iommu_groups/0/devices/0000:00:00.0
/sys/kernel/iommu_groups/9/devices/0000:00:1f.0
/sys/kernel/iommu_groups/9/devices/0000:00:1f.5
/sys/kernel/iommu_groups/9/devices/0000:00:1f.3
/sys/kernel/iommu_groups/9/devices/0000:00:1f.6
/sys/kernel/iommu_groups/9/devices/0000:00:1f.4
```

Finally, checking it is all set up properly:

```
# lspci -nnk
<snip>
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10d3]
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Gigabit CT Desktop Adapter [8086:a01f]
Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
Kernel modules: e1000e
```

And according to the documentation this last step says it should all be good to go.... So I am not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.
pfSense uses freeBSD and there is a bug in freeBSD that is preventing PCIe passthrough.
https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=243640

I verified this was my problem by creating a Fedora 31 VM and successfully passed through a WiFi PCIe NIC.

The solution is to wait for freeBSD to patch the kernel and for pfSense to incorporate it. I raised a bug for pfSense so they could track it (https://redmine.pfsense.org/issues/10315)

There is a lot of discussion about a workaround using i440fx but I could not get that to work.

- https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/vm-w-pcie-passthrough-not-working-after-upgrading-to-6-0.56021/
- https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=236922

It would be great if someone could give some guidance on how to implement the workaround.

Comment: I've spent more than 4 hours trying to investigate this and came upon this post. Thank you for saving the day Byron. The issue still persists but I've solved it by following the advice from Proxmox forum that Byron pointed. TLDR; Run the command below, replacing the ID to the ID of your VM `qm set ID -machine pc-q35-3.1`

Comment: Hi. The other tricked I worked out is, after setting the machine type to Q35, when you creat the machine do NOT select PCIe. Pass it through as PCI - and it all works.